# Why VS LoadTest PreRequest doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I wrote a Request plugin and override **Prequest**, it will assign a value,like "test 1" to a context parameter p1.

I add this Request plugin into my web service call. What i understand is in the Web service call, this new value "test 1" for p1 will be used in the string Body to send out the web service call.  But I just noticed, the new value "test 1" doesn't put into the string Body, the web service call is still using the default value. Why?   From VS view, I checked the result, looks like the new value is assigned to Context p1, why the web service call doesn't pick it up? weird.  Do I miss something? Thanks.

Comment: [edit] the question to include the text in the string body. To include the value of the context parameter `p1` in a string body enclose it in doubled curly braces. Something like `some text{{p1}}more text`. Case is significant.

Comment: I already use {{p1}}in the  string body, i can see the default value is used. So it means this is not the issue. the issue is once the value of p1 is changed, why the new value is not be picked up. If I put the assign the new value in **PostRequest** plugin function of the previous Web service call, the value is picked up by the following Web service call, but if I put the assign the new value in the **PreRequest** of this Web Service call, it won't work.

Comment: Then you should be using the `PreRequestDataBinding` method.

Comment: I have seen this problem on request level plugins. Somehow the event does not fire prerequest like it should. For a workaround I sometimes create the same parameter in a WebTestPluglin as well. So I have the same parameter in two places. 
The WebTestPlugin seems to get the parameter in the testcontext, and then the WebTestRequestPlugin will override it. It seems like that's the problem. The particular parameter in not in the testcontext, but the WebTestPlugin puts it in so then it can be overridden.